# Overflowing Underline While Being Responsive to Text Length

Tags: html, css, underline

I'm trying to emulate this effect via CSS:

[image]

The reason this is an issue is because it needs to be re-usable. The red underline's size should be dictated by the text length, but also overflow its container in a predictable manner, e.g.:

```
<div>
    <h1>This</h1>
    <h1>Cool</h1>
    <h1>Effect</h1>
</div>
```

The red underline should extend outside the div by 10px on the left, and then also overflow the text itself by roughly 50px on the right. So, all told, the red line is +60 pixels wider than the text itself.

How can I achieve this effect without doing it manually each time? I've had no success with pseudo elements, and box-shadow won't extend on the left and right as I need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo elements was the answer for me. Setting z-index on the :after element to get it positioned behind the parent element is a neat trick. The elements can't be block elements, but other than that it seemed straightforward.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0b122f 0%, #17457d 100%);
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  height: .25em;
  width: calc( 100% + 60px);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .15em;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>This</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>Cool</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>Effect</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn, I was so close! I gave up because of the z-indexing issue. You nailed it though. Thanks!

Comment: This works well if you don't have any section wrapping your underlined text. Z-index -1 will hide the line behind the section if this section has a color as background.

Answer (score 0):

use `<h1><span>This</span></h1>` make effect in span and adjust red box  to use padding to were's you want :

```
   h1 span {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 100px;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin: 0;
      padding:0 0 0 20px;
    }  
h1 span::before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  height: .25em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .15em;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

like: https://jsfiddle.net/bdmpqkme/1/

Answer (score 0):

All this examples mentioned above by lalit bhakuni and JasonB work really well, but only when you don't have any section with a background behind this underlined text.

The z-index: -1 will put the line you want behind the text like you want and also behind any other parent sections. In case any of these parent sections have a background, the line will be hidden (behind).

Other solution, not so clean, but solves all our problems is by adding an extra element inside of your heading:

HTML

```
<div class="div-with-background">
  <h1><span>This</span></h1>
  <br />
  <h1><span>Cool</span></h1>
  <br />
  <h1><span>Effect</span></h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div-with-background {
  background-color: #333;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

h1::before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  height: .25em;
  width: calc( 100% + 60px);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .15em;
  left: -10px;
}

h1 > span {
  position: relative;
}
```

In this case, we don't even need to use the z-index property.